# Auto-save render add-on

Tags: rendering

I have downloaded the auto-save render add-on, can anyone tell me where I can find the files after the render?

Thank you for your help

Comment: https://github.com/elfnor/blender_auto_save_on_render ... so maybe Documents/auto_saves?

Answer (score 1):

Auto-saved files are located in the same directory as your .blend file inside folder "auto_save".

To take script works you have to save your .blend file first.